# Reduce matrix to one single element per cell

Tags: java, matrix, java-stream

I have this input:

```
int [][] matrix = {{1, 2, 3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

And I'm trying to convert it to a matrix like the following using stream:

```
int [][] output = {{6}, {15}, {24}}
```

Which is the summation of the elements of each sub-array.

The code that I got so far is:

```
int[] array = Arrays.stream(matrix).map(a -> Arrays.stream(a).reduce(0, (subtotal, current) -> subtotal + current )).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Which results in the following array:

```
[6, 15, 24]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
int[][] matrix = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };

int[][] r = Arrays.stream(matrix)
        .map(a -> new int[]{IntStream.of(a).sum()})
        .toArray(int[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(r));
```

prints

```
[[6], [15], [24]]
```

- 2D arrays are arrays of arrays so the `Arrays.stream()` call streams the three arrays.
- the `IntStream` call streams each of those and sums them.
- the sum is then wrapped in an array and those arrays are wrapped in a 2D array.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way is:

```
int[][] result = new int[matrix.length][1];
IntStream.range(0, matrix.length)
         .forEach(i -> result[i][0] = Arrays.stream(matrix[i]).sum());
```

---

Thanks to [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) for commented another solution in below:

```
int[][] result = new int[matrix.length][]; 
Arrays.setAll(result, i -> new int[] { Arrays.stream(matrix[i]).sum() });
```

Comment: If you go that route, you can also use `int[][] result = new int[matrix.length][]; Arrays.setAll(result, i -> new int[] { Arrays.stream(matrix[i]).sum() });`

Comment: @Holger, definitely your solution is more elegant.thanks.